# JVM : When does JVM need to copy memory content

Tags: java, nio

I just read a wiki [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O#Channels), one of the passages said :

> Although theoretically these are general-purpose data structures, the
>   implementation may select memory for alignment or paging
>   characteristics, which are not otherwise accessible in Java.
>   Typically, this would be used to allow the buffer contents to occupy
>   the same physical memory used by the underlying operating system for
>   its native I/O operations, thus allowing the most direct transfer
>   mechanism, and eliminating the need for any additional copying

I am curious about the words "**eliminating the need for any additional copying**", when will JVM need this and why NIO could avoid it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670862/bytebuffer-allocate-vs-bytebuffer-allocatedirect

Answer (score 1):

It's talking about a direct mapping between a kernel data structure and a user space data structure; normally a context switch is required when moving between the two. However, with nio and a direct buffer, the context switch (and corresponding memory copies) does not occur.

Comment: Why context switch need memory copies ? Can you give me an example in Java ? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

From java.nio package API:

A byte buffer can be allocated as a direct buffer, in which case the Java virtual machine will make a best effort to perform native I/O operations directly upon it.

Example:

```
FileChannel fc = ...
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(8192);
int n = fc.read(buf);
```

Answer (score 0):

simply, old IO way always copy data from the kernel to memory in the heap. Using NIO allows to use buffers where file/network stream is mapped by the kernel directly. Result: less memory consumption and far better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Many developers know only a single JVM, the Oracle HotSpot JVM, and speak of garbage collection in general when they are referring to Oracle’s HotSpot implementation specifically. but the thing is check [Bob's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17310918/what-does-jvm-actually-do-if-i-read-a-large-string-from-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

New input/output (NIO) library, introduced with JDK 1.4, provides high-speed, block-oriented I/O in standard Java code.

Few points on NIO,

- IO is stream oriented, where NIO is buffer oriented.
- Offer   non-blocking I/O operations
- Avoid an extra copy of data passed    between Java and native memory
- Allows to read and write blocks of
  data direct from disk, rather than byte by byte

The NIO API introduces a new primitive I/O abstraction called channel. A channel represents an open connection to an entity such as a hardware device, a file, a network socket.
When you are using APIs FileChannel.transferTo() or FileChannel.transferFrom() JVM uses the OS's access to DMA (Direct Memory Access) which is potential advantage.

According to `Ron Hitches` on [Java NIO](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596002886.do)

> Direct buffers are intended for interaction with channels and native
>   I/O routines. They make a best effort to store the byte elements in a
>   memory area that a channel can use for direct, or raw, access by using
>   native code to tell the operating system to drain or fill the memory
>   area directly.
>
> Direct byte buffers are usually the best choice for I/O operations. By
>   design, they support the most efficient I/O mechanism available to the
>   JVM. Nondirect byte buffers can be passed to channels, but doing so
>   may incur a performance penalty. It's usually not possible for a
>   nondirect buffer to be the target of a native I/O operation.
>
> Direct buffers are optimal for I/O, but they may be more expensive to
>   create than nondirect byte buffers. The memory used by direct buffers
>   is allocated by calling through to native, operating system-specific
>   code, bypassing the standard JVM heap. Setting up and tearing down
>   direct buffers could be significantly more expensive than
>   heap-resident buffers, depending on the host operating system and JVM
>   implementation. The memory-storage areas of direct buffers are not
>   subject to garbage collection because they are outside the standard
>   JVM heap

Chapter 2 on below tutorial will give you more insight ( especially 2.4, 2.4.2 etc)
http://blogimg.chinaunix.net/blog/upfile2/090901134800.pdf